# Batch file with python script gives an error

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a python script in a batch file with the following code. This runs fine when I double click the .bat file to run it. However, when I run it through Task Scheduler it gives a 0x1 run error. I've tried experimenting and it seems removing the `>log.txt 2>&1` allows it to run from task scheduler. I added this line to log any exceptions and print statements to a txt file. Does anyone know why it causes an error with task scheduler but not when the batch file is manually executed?

```
python "C:\Users\XXX\untitled0.py" >log.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scheduled task runs with a working folder of (usually) `C:\Windwos\System32`, which is write protected.

Give the full path: `... > "%userprofile%\xxx\log.txt 2>&1`
or do a `cd /d "%~dp0` before to switch to the folder where your script is located.

Answer (score 0):

`0x1 run error` is cause by privilege error. In your case, the issue is probabily the fact the Task Scheduler lacks the privilege to write the `log.txt` file infact, as you have described, running the script with no `>log.txt 2>&1` has no issue.

Move the script to `"C:\untitled0.py"` and run it with the Task Scheduler from there